# How to make a specific cron expression for duration of 11 AM to 1 AM?

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

I need to create a cron expression equals "every hour from 11:00 AM to 1:00 AM every day every month every year) in another words, it is running only from 11:00 in the morning to 1 midnight every hour every day.

I have used different cron makers but neither could help me to create it such as

[Link 1](http://www.abunchofutils.com/utils/developer/cron-expression-helper/) 
[Link 2](http://www.cronmaker.com/)
[Link 3](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/tutorials/crontrigger)

I have made the followings but quartz trigger does not recognize them as valid expressions.

0 1 11-1 * * *

0 0 11-1 * * *

0 0 11-24 * * *

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: CronExpression '0 1 11-1 * * *' is invalid.
```

Comment: You many need to have two lines. `11-24` and `0-1`

Comment: I have made 0 0 11-24 * * * but it does not recognize it

Comment: 24 isn't recognized because the hour range is 0-23. To specify the midnight hour, use 0, as it is considered the first hour of the day.

Answer (score 3):

You can't specify a time that passes over the 24 hour boundary, but you can specify a comma-seperated list of ranges in your job entry. For example: 0 0 11-23,0-1 * * * [command]

Answer (score 1):

24 is totally wrong, zero equals to 12:00 AM, you need to have different ranges and use comma to separate them, you can make it as 0 0 11-0,0-1 ? * *